# Convexity of composite functions including monotonicity (inner functions are monotonic functions)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

**Problem**
$f$ is a convex function and $g$ is a monotonically increasing convex function.
Can we say that $f(g(x))$ is a convex function then?
Where $x\in\mathbb{R},f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},f(x)>0,g(x)>0,x>0$.

**What I know**
I know about the theorem that if $f$ is a monotonically increasing convex function and $g$ is convex, then $f(g(x))$ is a convex function. However this problem is monotonic in $g$, not $f$.

Please lend me your wisdom.

Comment: Please correct the spaces. It is not possible to have a composite function $f(g(x))$ with these spaces.

Comment: I have corrected some mistakes and simplified the problem a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the statement is not true. Take $g(x)=x^{3}$ convex and increasing for $x>0$ and

$f(y)=y^{2}-y+1$ which is convex.

Then $f(g(x))=x^{6}-x^{3}+1$ and $f'(x)=6x^{5}-3x^{2}$ and

$f''(x)=30x^{4}-6x=6x(5x^{3}-1)$ which is negative for $x<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}$.

Therefore $f(g(x))$ is concave on $[0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}]$

Comment: It is sad news to me that this statement is not true...But it really helped me. Thank you!